# How to switch between PeekDefinition popup and Editor, without using mouse and leaving the PD popup open?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I switch focus to the Visual Studio editor after I have `PeekDefinition` popup opened,  **without using mouse and leaving the PeekDefinition popup opened**?

With mouse, I could just click on the editor and it works. But I don't want to be reaching for the mouse every time I want to use the feature this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> will do what you want.

Here are some others you may find useful too:

- Open the definition window    <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>
- Close the definition window   <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- Promote the definition window to a regular document tab   <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>
- Navigate between definition windows   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I wanted. It toggles focus between the two! Thanks!